# PHP escape $ sign and echo a string my fetching database

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I want to know how to echo a string that have a $ sign from a database. At this time, the value on database 'Buy one for $5.00' converts to 'Buy one for .00'.

Let's say the name of the field is `title` and the value is `Buy one for $5.00`

```
<?php

$body_tpl = file_get_contents('tpl.html'); //Title is: %title% blah blah %title%

$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT title FROM table WHERE id=1"));
$title = $row['title'];
$pat[] = '/%title%/sx';
$rep[] = $title;
$body = preg_replace($pat,$rep,$body_tpl);

print_r($body);

?>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code pointing towards anything that could convert the amount like that. Can you show the full code? Are you 100% certain it's in `$5.00` form in the database?

Comment: I have edited the question and it contains the full code.

Comment: Are you echoing a string within double quotes? If so, PHP might be trying to do string interpolation, thinking that the dollar sign starts a variable.

Comment: I think so... It's a pretty big file and some places and some included files contains ' and other contains ". However, to print the page, I was using preg_replace but after having the following answer, I've changed it to str_replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use str_replace for that.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array.....
$title = $row['title'];
$body = str_replace( "%title%", $title, $body_tpl );
echo $body;
```

Note that you can replace multiple keywords at the same time with str_replace too (see PHP docs).